# Java - Search ArrayList of JsonArrays

Tags: java, json, gson

I am looking to search an ArrayList of JsonArrays for a given value. Below is an example of the data that is contained within my ArrayList `valueList`:

```
[
  [
    {
      "blobJson": "x",
      "deviceMfg": 10,
      "eventCode": 0,
      "sensorClass": 3,
      "sensorUUID": "15633094",
      "timeStamp": 1485433626.504731,
      "uID": "15633094_3_10"
    },
    {
      "blobJson": "x",
      "deviceMfg": 10,
      "eventCode": 0,
      "sensorClass": 3,
      "sensorUUID": "19458142",
      "timeStamp": 1483916820.538747,
      "uID": "19458142_3_10"
    },
    {
      "blobJson": "x",
      "deviceMfg": 10,
      "eventCode": 1,
      "sensorClass": 3,
      "sensorUUID": "22808642",
      "timeStamp": 1485937952.330456,
      "uID": "22808642_3_10"
    }
  ]
]
```

I am looking to search through `valueList` for the value of the `timeStamp` field and extract it, how can I do this?

(I'm using the GSON library to parse JSON)

Comment: Your question is not clear: are you trying to search for a specific property and the hold timestamp, or you have to filter out against a specific value of an object (there at least three `timeStamp`s there), or are you trying just to extract timestamps? (Hint: you might probably want to use `List<List<JsonObject>>` rather than `ArrayList<JsonArray>`.)

Comment: I'm just trying to extract the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8, you can use the Streams API in order to extract the timestamps:

```java
private static final TypeToken<List<List<JsonObject>>> listOfListOfJsonObjectsTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<List<JsonObject>>>() {
};
```

```java
final List<List<JsonObject>> arrays = gson.fromJson(JSON, listOfListOfJsonObjectsTypeToken.getType());
final List<Double> timestamps = arrays.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(jo -> jo.get("timeStamp"))
        .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonPrimitive)
        .map(JsonPrimitive::getAsDouble)
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(timestamps);
```

gives:

> [1.485433626504731E9, 1.483916820538747E9, 1.485937952330456E9]

---

**Edit:**

You might also want to use a JSON queryng library like [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) that was designed to query JSON objects:

```java
final DocumentContext context = JsonPath.parse(JSON);
final JSONArray timestampsJsonArray = context.read(JsonPath.compile("$[0][*].timeStamp"));
final List<Double> timestamps = timestampsJsonArray.stream()
        .map(o -> (Number) o)
        .map(Number::doubleValue)
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(timestamps);
```

which would give exactly the same result.

**Edit 2**

If no JSON parsing/processing is assumed, you can use:

```
final List<Double> timeStamps = valueList.stream()
        .flatMap(ja -> StreamSupport.stream(ja.spliterator(), false))
        .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
        .map(jo -> jo.get("timeStamp"))
        .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonPrimitive)
        .map(JsonPrimitive::getAsDouble)
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(timeStamps);
```

Results the same.

Comment: What goes in place of `JSON` and `listOfListOfJsonObjectsTypeToken` in the line `gson.fromJson(JSON, listOfListOfJsonObjectsTypeToken.getType());`

Comment: @ColinShewell `JSON` - the JSON document you provided in the question; `listOfListOfJsonObjectsTypeToken` -- the `private static final` field I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: The JSON document in the question is stored as a `ArrayList`, when I put this in place of `JSON` it is giving a method not found error.

Comment: @ColinShewell I assumed you can pass the JSON document to the querying code since you mentioned Gson, and there are many ways to query JSON documents. See the answer update.